Unable to use a context within async fetcher function for useSWR
I use SWR 2.2.5 within Next.js 14.2 to load data from my node.js server. I need to send a header with access token for authorization to get the data back. The token comes from an AuthContext with which I wrap all of my application.
I'm able to add the header to the async fetch request but as soon as I try to get the currentUser from the custom useAuth hook (uncomment const { currentUser } = useAuth()) I don't get an error but also I see that there is no request sent to the server.
Here is my code:
'use client'

import useSWR from "swr";
import { useAuth } from "@/contexts/AuthContext";

let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");

async function fetcher([url, token]) {
    // const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    // const idToken = currentUser ? await currentUser.getIdToken() : "unauthorized"; 
    // token.append('authorization', idToken);

    const response = await fetch(url, { headers: token })
    const data = await response.json()
    return data
}

const Page = () => {

    const { data } = useSWR(
        [process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_PATH + "test", headers],
        fetcher
    );

    console.log("data:", data)
    return <h1>{data && "do something with data here"}</h1>

};
  
 export default Page;
  

Any help appreciated, thanks!
